# Gitlab-CI not recognize the yml on the folders

Tags: java, maven, continuous-integration, gitlab

So i have multiple folders inside a empty IDEA project and each folder has a pom.xml.

I need to deploy each folder separately but gitlab ci only recognize the main folder which is the empty project.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your achitecture well, you should have a separate git repository for each of your folders in the parent IDEA project.

It would look like that :

```
/rootProject
  |- gitRepo1
    |- .gitlab-ci.yml
  |- gitRepo2
    |- .gitlab-ci.yml
  |- gitRepo3
    |- .gitlab-ci.yml
```

This way you can have separate CI pipelines and deployments for each subfolder.

There is an open issue considering the possibility to change the default location of the .gitlab-ci.yml file, but it is not yet available :
  https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/15041